# Syntax error on Ubuntu Command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am not familiar with `Linux`, just basic commands, I want to use the command below on `Ubuntu` but I get syntax error.

**Command:**

```
curl --progress-bar "http://community.nanocloud.com/nanocloud.sh" | sh
```

**Error:**

```
sh: 2: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the content of the downloaded file first (e.g. using wget instead of curl) and then run sh on the saved file.

```
wget "http://community.nanocloud.com/nanocloud.sh";
sh nanocloud.sh
```